# How to obtain a list of values from a Data.AVL.Tree?

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I'm easily able to obtain a list of Keys, as follows:

```
open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_)

module AVL-Tree-Functions
  { k v ℓ } { Key : Set k }
  ( Value : Key → Set v )
  { _<_ : Rel Key ℓ }
  ( isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_ )
  where

  open import Data.AVL Value isStrictTotalOrder public

  open import Data.List.Base
  open import Function
  open import Data.Product

  keys : Tree → List Key
  keys = Data.List.Base.map proj₁ ∘ toList
```

But I'm not clear on how to specify the type of function that returns a list of values. Here's my first attempt:

```
  -- this fails to typecheck
  values : Tree → List Value
  values = Data.List.Base.map proj₂ ∘ toList
```

Relatedly, I'm also confused about the declaration of `Value` in Data.AVL. With `( Value : Key → Set v )`, it looks like the type of each Value in the tree is dependent on the key? Or, something like that. I then figured that proj₂ would be returning something of type `Set v`, so I tried this:

```
  -- this also fails to typecheck
  values : Tree → List (Set v)
  values = Data.List.Base.map proj₂ ∘ toList
```

But that doesn't work either (it fails with a different error). Please show how to get a list of values from a Data.AVL.Tree (or explain why it's impossible). Bonus: explain why my two attempts failed.

P.s. This is using version 2.4.2.3 of Agda and the agda-stdlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it looks like the type of each Value in the tree is dependent on the
>   key?

Yes. And that's why your code doesn't typecheck — `List`s are homogeneous, but different `Value`s have different indices (i.e. depend on different `Key`s) and hence different types.

You can use heterogeneous lists as in **gallais**' answer, but indexed lists might be enough in your case:

```
open import Level

data IList {ι α} {I : Set ι} (A : I -> Set α) : Set (ι ⊔ α) where
  []ᵢ  : IList A
  _∷ᵢ_ : ∀ {i} -> A i -> IList A -> IList A

projs₂ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : A -> Set β} -> List (Σ A B) -> IList B
projs₂  []            = []ᵢ
projs₂ ((x , y) ∷ ps) = y ∷ᵢ projs₂ ps
```

Or you can combine the techniques:

```
data IHList {ι α} {I : Set ι} (A : I -> Set α) : List I -> Set (ι ⊔ α) where
  []ᵢ  : IHList A []
  _∷ᵢ_ : ∀ {i is} -> A i -> IHList A is -> IHList A (i ∷ is)

projs₂ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : A -> Set β}
       -> (xs : List (Σ A B)) -> IHList B (Data.List.Base.map proj₁ xs)
projs₂  []            = []ᵢ
projs₂ ((x , y) ∷ ps) = y ∷ᵢ projs₂ ps
```

Answer (score 3):

What `Value : Key → Set v` means is that the type of the value may depend on the key it is associated to. This means that an AVL tree may contain Booleans, Nats, and so on as long as the key they are stored in reflects that fact. A bit like the fact that records can store values of different types (the types are determined by the field's name).

Now, they are different ways to do this: you can extract the content of the whole tree to a list of key / value pairs (because a list's elements are all the same, you need to build a pair here so that everything has the same type `Σ Key Value`). This is what `toList` does.

An alternative is to use what is usually called an `HList` (the H stands for heterogeneous) which stores in a list *at the type level* the type each one of its elements is supposed to have. I define it here by induction on the set of elements for size reasons but it is not at all crucial (if you were to define it as a datatype, it would live one level higher):

```
open import Level
open import Data.Unit

HList : {ℓ : Level} (XS : List (Set ℓ)) → Set ℓ
HList []       = Lift ⊤
HList (X ∷ XS) = X × HList XS
```

Now, you can give the type of the `HList` of values. Given `t` a `Tree`, it uses your `keys` to extract the list of keys and turns them into `Set`s by mapping `Value` over the list.

```
values : (t : Tree) → HList (List.map Value (keys t))
```

Extracting the values can then be done with the help of an auxiliary function working along the list produced by `toList`:

```
values t = go (toList t) where

  go : (kvs : List (Σ Key Value)) → HList (List.map Value $ List.map proj₁ kvs)
  go []         = lift tt
  go (kv ∷ kvs) = proj₂ kv , go kvs
```

Comment: It was hard to decide between gallais' and user3237465's answers. I went with user3237465's because the 'indexed list' approach is exactly enough to solve my particular problem. Thanks and hats off to gallais for this excellent and informative answer.